# Leaflet screen distance to LatLng distance

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to combine markers based on the zoom level. I'm not using Markercluster but my own algorithm to detect which markers should be combined. This algorithm works perfectly fine. The only thing I have to add is a zoom-based condition when the markers should be combined. Currently, all markers within a distance of 0.001 get combined. What I want is that every marker within a distance of 0.5cm on the screen gets combined. So I need a function that converts a distance in cm, px, or something else into a distance in degree.

An example: On zoom-level 18, two markers with a distance of 0.00005 in the longitude have a distance of nearly 0.3cm on my screen.

**EDIT:**
So this is what I did:

```
function in_range(location1, location2, map) {
    return get_distance_in_px(location1, location2, map) < 25;
}

function get_distance_in_px(location1, location2, map) {
    var p1 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(L.latLng(location1[0], location1[1]));
    var p2 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(L.latLng(location2[0], location2[1]));

    var a = p1.x - p2.x;
    var b = p1.y - p2.y;

    return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
}
```

Comment: There have been years since I worked with Leaflet, I will only be able to help if you create a JSFiddle so I can play around it.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to achieve is reproducible as screen resolution is different so your 0.3cm worth of pixels isn't the same across all devices.
I don't really see a reason why not using MarkerCluster in the first place.

Comment: @Souhailhimself in general I would solve this for *my* screen resolution first and when that's correct, do some tests with other resolutions and apply some changes. At first I ignore the variability of screen resolution, that would be a second step.

Comment: @LajosArpad I personally believe this isn't the best way to approach this but you can read more about the zoom and how it works from [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/) you'll get my point then.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the containerPoint of the latlngs and then calculate the distance:

```
map.on('zoomend',(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
    recalcZoom();
});

var DISTANCE = 20; //px
function recalcZoom() {
    var layers = findLayers(map);
    var resultLayers = []; //sturcture: {main: layer, childs: [];
    layers.forEach((layer)=>{
        if(resultLayers.length === 0){ // set the first layer as main layer
            resultLayers.push({
                main: layer,
                childs: []
            });
        }else{
            var found = false;
            var mainObj = null;
            var lastDis = null;
            resultLayers.forEach((rLayer)=>{
                var main = rLayer.main;
                var p1 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(main.getLatLng());
                var p2 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(layer.getLatLng());
                var dis = p1.distanceTo(p2);
                if(dis <= DISTANCE){ // distance between main layer and current marker is lower then DISTANCE
                    if(lastDis == null || dis < lastDis) { // a main layer is found, where the distance between them is lower
                        if(mainObj && mainObj.childs.indexOf(layer) > -1){ // remove the layer from the old main layer childs array
                            mainObj.splice(mainObj.childs.indexOf(layer),1);
                        }

                        rLayer.childs.push(layer);
                        found = true;
                        mainObj = rLayer;
                    }
                }
            });
            if(!found){ // if no main layer is found, add it as new main layer
                resultLayers.push({
                    main: layer,
                    childs: []
                });
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(resultLayers);
    // Logic to find center of all childs + main
    // remove the old layers and add the new clustered layer
    // keep in mind, that you have to store somewhere the original markers, else you can't recalc the clusters
}

function findLayers(map) {
// your logic to get the original layers
    let layers = [];
    map.eachLayer(layer => {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            layers.push(layer);
        }
    });
    return layers;
}
```

You have to implement by yourself the logic to find center of all childs + main layer, then remove the old layers and add the new clustered layer.
But keep in mind, that you have to store somewhere the original markers, else you can't recalc the clusters.

Little Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/ny9s17cb/ (look into the console)

Answer (score 0):

A note from the Leaflet Examples

> One of the disadvantages of using a cylindrical projection is that the
> scale is not constant, and measuring distances or sizes is not
> reliable, especially at low zoom levels.
>
> In technical terms, the cylindrical projection that Leaflet uses is
> conformal (preserves shapes), but not equidistant (does not preserve
> distances), and not equal-area (does not preserve areas, as things
> near the equator appear smaller than they are).
> [**learn more**](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/#a-note-about-scale)

After that being said you're really getting yourself into so many more problems trying to get the dimension exact where they aren't reliable measurements to start with.